# CLPPLUS command stops after execution, so the other commands are not processed

Tags: batch-file, db2, sqlanywhere, clpplus

Situation:

autoMark.cmd:

```
...
clpplus user/pw@DB2database:50000/db @autoMarkDB2.sql 01.02.2016 02.02.2016

%DBISQL% -c "uid=user;pwd=pw;dsn=SA16database" READ autoMarkSA.sql 742987 742989
...
```

autoMarkDB2.sql: (IBM DB2 9.7 or something)

```
simple select statement with the parameters called &1 &2;
exit;
```

autoMarkSA.sql: (SQL Anywhere Server 16)

```
PARAMETER a,b;
simple select statement with the parameters called {a}, {b};
OUTPUT TO out.txt;
```

If i either call clpplus or dbisql own their own, they work fine and give the right results. but if put them in this order like above, the clpplus command is processed, the results are shown in the clpplus window, but it never closes. so the program stops there, waiting for my input.
If i call exit or quit manually, the clpplus windows closes, but the program is still not processing further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i just had to use "call" in front of the clpplus.

Comment: You should never ask two totally unrelated questions within a single "Question". StackOverflow is not a typical "forum"; it's a Q&A site. Since your second question has nothing to do with the title you should: 1) Remove it from the Question (click the "Edit" link to do so); 2) Mark your "Answer" as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark next to it; 3) Start a NEW question with a meaningful title for your second question. Your chances of getting help will be much better!

Comment: need to wait another day to flag my own answer

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11157398)